# Error in inflating a ConstraintLayout when doing a test Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, testing, android-espresso

I´m trying to do a test in android studio, and the fragment i´m trying to launch has a ConstraintLayout, I've seen other responses of this type of error but none of them were useful. The error I get is this one:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.museosgijon:layout/fragment_list_museum: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.museosgijon:layout/fragment_list_museum: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.museosgijon:layout/fragment_list_museum: Error inflating class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:663)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at com.example.museosgijon.databinding.FragmentListMuseumBinding.inflate(FragmentListMuseumBinding.java:56)
at com.example.museosgijon.ui.ListMuseumFragment.onCreateView(ListMuseumFragment.kt:54)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2995)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:523)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1758)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1670)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:317)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$Companion.internalLaunch$lambda-2(FragmentScenario.kt:628)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$Companion.$r8$lambda$qQn68eFQCuWOFZCsJdZ7z8QDNvM(Unknown Source:0)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$Companion$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.perform(Unknown Source:13)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$2$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:660)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$4.run(ActivityScenario.java:652)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at android.app.Instrumentation$SyncRunnable.run(Instrumentation.java:2296)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 18: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f030004 a=-1}
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:783)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5567)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:702)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:698)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:694)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.<init>(ConstraintLayout.java:567)
```

When I run the aplication I dont get any error and it launches.

The dependencie of the constraintlayout is like this:
`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'`

And in the xml its defined in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".ui.ListMuseumFragment"
    android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have some error on line #2 in XML file "fragment_list_museum".
Please paste **fragment_list_museum.xml** for more help.

• In XML it looks all good. I don't know, what's wrong...
Maybe try updating implementation to 2.1.4, but it wouldn't help, I think. Maybe someone else will find answer.

Comment: Just added, I´ve tried to do the exact same test in other proyect with a view with a constraintlayout and it passes the test... but in this proyect doesnt

Comment: Maybe is something wrong with GRADLE file

Comment: Using the "same" gradle file of the proyect that gives an error in the proyect that doesnt, it still works

Comment: So if it's not a big project, make new project and copy all code